# regex for name verification

Tags: regex

I am trying to build a regex that fulfills these requirements, but I am not sure how to do it. I tried with:

```
[A-Z][a-z]+[,][ ][A-z][a-z]+($|[[ ]{0,1}[A-Z][.]]{0,1})
```

but it's not doing what I want. I need some help.

Requirements

> **Last**, **First M**.

**Last** - must begin with a capital letter and be followed by one more lower case letters.

**First** - must begin with a capital letter and be followed by one or more lower case letters.

**M.** - must be a single capital letter followed by a period (.). This part (including the preceding space) is optional.

Examples of valid accepted strings are:

- "Davis, Mike"
- "Leppla, David A."

Invalid examples are:

- "D, Mike"
- "L, David"
- "Smith, Joe "  (with an extra space on the end)
- "smith, Mike"
- "Jo, Fr a."

Comment: No, don't do this.

Comment: Marshall McLuhan and Bill O'Reilly come to mind...

Comment: I think what ctwheels means is that if you want to extract them for existing data, maybe that can be justified, but don't use this to try to validate a name a user enters in an input: i recommend this reading: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: @Kaddath thank you, I was looking for that article, but couldn't remember where it was.

Comment: Your pattern suffers from the second group of capitals, where a lower z is used instead of an upper one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you the following regex to be compliant with your requirements:

```
[A-Z][a-z]+, [A-Z][a-z]+( [A-Z]\.)?
```